# Split column value into dynamic columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `table1` with the following column:

```
file_name
dqID.AB_RES_ZEST_H2O_XYZ.LKG774548_00035_CAB_TS_HEST_H99_WED_45430098138.txt_154853452388.txt.xml
dqID.AB_RES_ZEST_H2O_XYZ.LKG744348_022335_CAB_TS_HEST_H99_WED_445438138.txt_15344452388.txt.xml
dqID.AB_RES_ZEST_H2O_XYZ.LKG774548_000435_CAB_TS_HEST_H99_WED_45345138.txt_15485343458.txt.xml
```

I'm looking to create dynamic number of columns based on the values and split using _ and .

So, the output would be:

```
file_name                                                                                                  part1    part2   part3   part4......
dqID.AB_RES_ZEST_H2O_XYZ.LKG774548_00035_CAB_TS_HEST_H99_WED_45430098138.txt_154853452388.txt.xml           dqID     AB     RES   ZEST....
dqID.AB_RES_ZEST_H2O_XYZ.LKG744348_022335_CAB_TS_HEST_H99_WED_445438138.txt_15344452388.txt.xml             dqID     AB     RES   ZEST....
dqID.AB_RES_ZEST_H2O_XYZ.LKG774548_000435_CAB_TS_HEST_H99_WED_45345138.txt_15485343458.txt.xml              dqID     AB     RES   ZEST....
```

Is there anyway in Oracle SQL to split the text into multiple parts using 2 `_` and `.`

Also, create part columns dynamically? Because the string can contain either a lot of `_` & `.` or very few `_` & `.`

Comment: A sql query must return a fixed set of columns, so the *dynamic* part cannot be performed in pure SQL : you would need to use dynamic SQL, eg with a stored procedure. But what would be the point of generating such output?

Comment: I need to split it up, so I can do my analysis. Metadata is emdedded in the string which needs to be operated on.

Comment: Is it possible to do it with 20 fixed columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, a sql query must return a *fixed* set of columns, so the dynamic part cannot be performed in pure SQL.

Here is a solution that uses `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` to split the string over a fixed number of columns:

```
SELECT
    file_name,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_name, '[^._]+', 1, 1) as part1,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_name, '[^._]+', 1, 2) as part2,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_name, '[^._]+', 1, 3) as part3
FROM table1
```

You can add as many columnms as needed in the resultset.

Regexp explanation:

```
[             # any character
    ^         #     other than
        .     #         a dot
        _     #         or an underscore
]             #
+             # occuring at least once
```

So basically this will capture string portions in between separators `.` and `_`.